# StreamWriter Argument is no legal

Tags: c#, serialization, stream

I am trying to serialize an Object by method using the StreamWriter but somehow I can not dynamically define the path to the file.

Example:

```
public void SerializeToXML(Record aRecord)
{
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Movie));

  var path = string.Format("@\"{0}\\{1}.xml\"", "C:\\Objects", aRecord.GetHashCode());

  TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path);

  serializer.Serialize(textWriter, movie);

  textWriter.Close();
}
```

And then it says: `"Illegal characters in path" on the line :TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path);`

When I am passinging it staticaly it wokrs with this format but when I want to pas it dymanicaly it doesnt accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Your path starts with an `@` sign. I don't think you want it to. I suspect you were *trying* to use a verbatim string literal, but got a bit confused. I suspect you just want:

```
var path = string.Format(@"C:\Objects\{0}.xml", aRecord.GetHashCode());
```

Alternatively, you could work out the filename first, then root it using `Path.Combine`.

Note that using `GetHashCode` in a filename is almost always a bad idea. It's not guaranteed to be unique, and it has no real meaning other than as a first pass at an equality check. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but it's almost certainly the wrong approach.

Also, you should use a `using` statement for your writer:

```
using (var writer = File.CreateText(path))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, movie);
}
```